# Docker how to use env_file variable in Dockerfile during build

Tags: docker-compose, dockerfile

I would like to use `STAGE` variable from `env_file` in my `Dockerfile`. Most posts suggest just use `-e` with `docker-compose up` command but I would like to achieve this by the `env_file`.

I tried add `args` but it's not working.

**Env file**

```
STAGE=DEV
```

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - /etc/web.env
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
```

**Dockerfile**

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
(...)
RUN pip install -r project/requirements/$STAGE.txt
```

**Result of this should be:**

```
RUN pip install -r project/requirements/DEV.txt
```

I found that it is not possible during build but maybe exist some method to do this. I will be helpful for any tips.

Comment: Try using args as referred https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/#args

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can map the environment variable into the container by adding an `environment` option in your docker compose yaml file:

```
version: '2'

services:
  web:
    build: .
    env_file:
      - /etc/web.env
    command: python3 manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
    volumes:
      - ./backend:/code
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"
    environment:
      - STAGE: ${STAGE}
```

Comment: I tried it earlier and received: `ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
services.web.environment contains {"STAGE": ""}, which is an invalid type, it should be a string`

Comment: It's because the `STAGE` env var is not set in your local environment. You can run `export $(cat envfile | grep -v '^#')` before running `docker-compose up` (replace `envfile` to your environment file name)

Comment: The approach above is to set the environment variables in your local machine, then map them into your docker container. An alternative approach that might work is to map your env file into the container and export them. You can add a line `- ./envfile:/code/envfile` in your `volumes` setting, then do `RUN export $(cat /code/envfile | grep -v '^#') && pip install ...`

Comment: unfortunately I can't access to my `env file` even if it is in `volumes`.

Comment: then try the first approach (export from the file in local and map the env vars as environment into container)